# Vertex Cover Proof

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I am working on an exercise describe like so:

Without using knowledge about cliques, prove that a graph G has an independent set of size k if and only if G has a vertex cover of size n - k where n is the size of V, the vertex set of G.

I am attempting to write a proof for this and was hoping for help with the concept and wording.

By definition of independent sets, the complement of independent set of size k will result in every vertex being connected by an edge to form a maximum clique size of n - k.

Is this sufficient enough or how should I add to it to make it concrete?

Comment: Your sketch seems to me to assume knowledge about cliques.

Comment: If a graph had n vertices and no edges, then would its vertex cover be non-existent? I thought that vertex covers were the minimum set of vertices such that every edge in the graph is attached to at least one vertex in the set.

Comment: @raphnguyen I misunderstood the definition of vertex cover when I wrote that comment (which is why it's now deleted). Please disregard it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be an independent set of size $k$ in $G$. The set $V(G) \setminus I$ is a vertex cover of the desired size. It covers every edge in the graph because there can be no edges between vertices of $I$. In other words, every edge of $G$ has some endpoint lying in $V(G) \setminus I$, and these are precisely the vertices in the proposed cover.

Comment: Hi Austin, I am unfamiliar with the forward slash notation V(G) \ I. Can you please elaborate on this? Thanks.

Comment: It means those vertices of $G$ that do not belong to $I$. It is sometimes called "set difference", since you are starting with the elements of the first set and removing the elements of the second set.

Comment: Thanks, Austin. So every vertex in I is connected by an edge to at least one vertex in V(G) \ I. Vertices in V(G) \ I would then form the minimum vertex cover. Is there ever an instance where this does not result in the "minimum" vertex cover?

Comment: The construction I gave gives *a* vertex cover, but it is not always going to be the minimum. If you read at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover, you'll see that determining the minimum vertex cover of a graph is NP-Complete (which basically means "very difficult"). An example where $n - k$ is not the minimum, take a triangle and attach a pendant edge to each vertex. This has an independent set of size 3, but the minimum vertex cover is of size 2, not 3, as the proposition we proved gives.

Comment: @raphnguyen My pleasure. We seem to be browsing SE at precisely the same time every day.

Comment: My example should say "attach a pendant edge to two of the vertices of the triangle".

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar question to this one in $2^{nd}$ part of:  [Question asking relation between vertex cover and independent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2553679/question-asking-relation-between-vertex-cover-and-independent-set). My answer to that question might be a simpler argument using the definitions given in that question:

Since a vertex cover $C$ includes at least one end point of each edge, $V(G)−C$ must include either none of the endpoints of one edge or 1 of them. So it is an independent set by definition. Assuming $|V(G)| = n$, if $G$ has an independent set of size $k$, then we can find a vertex cover of size $n-k$. And same argument also holds for converse, that is, if $G$ has a vertex cover of size $n-k$, we can find an independent set of size $k$.

This may not be a different approach but I thought it can be helpful with the definitions given and supporting the argument here by using the argument asked in [Question asking relation between vertex cover and independent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2553679/question-asking-relation-between-vertex-cover-and-independent-set).